# CIFS/SAMBA Mount still attempts before network is ready even with _netdev

Tags: linux, networking, samba, cifs

The title gives a pretty good synopsis. I am running a debian derivative (osmc) on a raspberry pi 2 in this case. and am trying to mount a share. It mounts 100% a ok from the command line or just using `mount -a` with the exact same `/etc/fstab` but on boot it does not come up, no matter what settings I tweak.

The entry in `/etc/fstab` is:

```
//192.168.10.100/music  /mnt/musicshare cifs    guest,_netdev   0       0
```

I've checked `dmesg` and it shows the mount clearly trying to occur before the network is up:

```
[    6.039309] input: lircd as /devices/virtual/input/input4
[    6.511610] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    6.512123] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[    6.763291] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[    6.763690] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    7.188820] systemd-journald[105]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    8.486622] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[    8.496643] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
[    8.527928] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   12.458908] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x30
[   36.929687] Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x3 frame 729 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
[   37.309752] Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x3 frame 1109 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
```

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: 1. stp on switch? (try to plug off for a while, reboot and then connect again - then check if mount -a hangs/timeouts). 2. move cifsmount in /etc/rc2.d/ to "later on the list" like S03->S93. 3. mount -a to rc.local as a workaround

Comment: Thanks! First two were a no go. There isn't even a cifsmount in and of the rc levels. And at first the last didn't work. But once I popped a sleep 5 in there it sure did.

 sleep 5
mount -a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have an up-to-date version of osmc running, use the following options instead:

> x-systemd.automount,noauto

This results in a systemd automount unit being created. See [systemd.automount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html#) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that, I do appreciate the improvement upon my method. Furthermore, I was having trouble after the recent updated package and had to specifically set the `sec=ntlmv2` in `/etc/fstab` . Following this thread from the [osmc forums](https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/smb-shares-cannot-browse-after-update/3294)

Comment: When did the `_netdev` option become obsolete?